# Reload function usage in Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, reload

I read a lot on reload but I am not able to use reload function.There is some error in imp.py itself.I didn't make any changes.

```
>>> import imp
>>> imp.reload('fileread')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    imp.reload('fileread')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 258, in reload
    raise TypeError("reload() argument must be module")
TypeError: reload() argument must be module
```

fileread is stored in proper directory of python.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass actual module objects to `imp.reload()`.

If you only have the module *name*, look up the module object in the [`sys.modules` mapping](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
import sys
import imp

imp.reload(sys.modules['fileread'])
```

This only works on modules that have already been imported; if some of your entries are not imported yet, at the very least catch the `KeyError` skip these:

```
try:
    imp.reload(sys.modules[modulename])
except KeyError:
    # not loaded, no point in reloading
    pass
```

Optionally, you could use [`importlib.import_module()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to load such modules instead.

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> import imp
>>> imp.reload(sys.modules['fileread'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    imp.reload(sys.modules['fileread'])
KeyError: 'fileread'                                                  I am still getting error

Comment: @PavanRavishankar: Then the module is *not imported*. Import `fileread` first; at that point there is no need to reload either.